# Add additional or custom filtering field to GridView (Yii2)

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Aside from the column filtering in the GridView, I wanted to include custom fields or two additional fields outside of GridView that filters along with it. I have a table called card numbers and I wanted to include a search of range of the card numbers. I wanted to include the fields above the table in which the user will input a range of the card numbers to view or to be filtered out but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS class to the fields like `additionalFilter` and in the GridView configuration add

```
'filterSelector' => '.additionalFilter',
```

Now GridView will use the inputs with this class as more filters.